# Correlation with Spearman's but nothing on MLR

Tags: regression, correlation

How is it possible that individually, Z correlates with X and Y (Spearman's) but when multivariate linear regression analysis is done X and Y cannot predict Z at all. Am I doing something wrong? This doesn't make sense to me.